# Ubuntu cannot boot problems

Tags: boot, startup, root, recovery-mode, resume

I use Ubuntu 18.04 and it worked well, but when I turned on my computer this morning, the following problem occured.

[Problem screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1oJ9b.jpg)

I am fairly new to Linux and have no idea what this could mean but I would like to resolve this. Did someone have the same problem? How can I fix it?

Comment: Google recovery mode, activate it, do `fsck` and `network` options in the menu, then drop to root prompt (shell) and type `dmesg | less` there, look for actual fail or error messages, the last portion may be the most interesting also, as that are the last executed/attempted things. If nothing there, then check the other files in `/var/log/` for the same (dmesg displays only one of them). `.gz` files can be viewed with `zcat name | less`. Then the information in https://askubuntu.com/q/162075/289138 may have ways to "fix it". If NOT, then edit new info into your question for evaluation.